# What's the meaning of the length of glide reflection?

Tags: geometry

Problem 4 of [this sheet](http://www.csun.edu/~ac53971/courses/math623/hmwk03.pdf) states:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a discontinuous, fixed point free group of glide reflections and translations. Let $g$ be a glide reflection of minimal length in $\Gamma$, and let $h$ be an element of minimal length in $\Gamma$ not in the direction
>   of $g$. Prove that $g$ and $h$ must have perpendicular directions (e.g., by finding shorter elements when the directions of $g$ and $h$ are not perpendicular).

This refers to a glide reflection with minimal length, but what's the definition of the length here, does that mean the length of the translation in the glide reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say yes, the length of the glide reflection is the translational component. If you apply a glide reflection twice you obtain a translation, and half it's distance is what I'd call the length or distance of the glide reflection.

Comment: Thank you, and do you have any idea about problem 4?

Comment: @Joseph: My first approach would go through the classification of [wallpaper groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group). Looking at that classification, I notice that there are no wallpaper groups consisting *solely* of translations and at least two different kinds of glide reflections. That's because two independent glide reflections combine to form a rotation. So you can't read the question as *only* reflections and translations. But if you allow other isometries in $\Gamma$ as well, why not reflections? Then you can find counterexamples, e.g. p31m. So I'd disagree with the claim.